# Xubuntu 15.04: Thunderbird new mail alert not showing

Tags: xubuntu, 15.04, thunderbird, postfix, mail-notification

I'm an unexperienced Ubuntu user. I re-installed Xubuntu 15.04 a couple of days ago and I am not getting the new mail notifications for `Thunderbird` (I think I may have been getting them at the start, but not sure I remember right).

I checked under Thunderbird preferences. The "`show an alert`" box under "`when a new message arrives`" is ticked. I also checked forums for an answer and could not find anything.
Can someone help please?

Answer (score 2):

Install plugin **Mailbox Alert** in Thunderbird

After that you can customize a lot :)

Also maybe you will be interested in notifications for chat: **Thunderbird Chat Notification**

Another interesting plugin is **FireTray** to run Thunderbird in background.

**IMPORTANT** You won't get notifications if Thunderbird isn't running.

Sample how to activate notifications for Mailbox Alert
[image]